# Google Compute Engine OS Login is not active

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a Google App Engine Flask app that is publishing (via `pubsub_v1`) to a pubsub every minute using `cron.yaml` and a Google Compute Engine that is picking up the message, similar to [this example](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine). Every minute the GCE app prints out the messages the GAE app sent, but every few minutes I am getting a message in the GCE log saying "Google Compute Engine OS Login is not active." This will happen for 6 - 10 minutes, then the GCE app will start printing out the messages again. What does this message mean and how can I fix it?

When I Google search "Google Compute Engine OS Login is not active", nothing comes up, which is odd for something that appears to be some sort of error.

EDIT:

Here's the GCE script

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import time
import os
import sys
import datetime
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
import string


project = 'xxx'
topic_name = 'my-new-topic'

from google.cloud import logging

logging_client = logging.Client()
log_name = 'xxx'
logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)

engine = create_engine('xxx')

# The data to log
text = '################### STARTING GCE ###################'

# Writes the log entry
logger.log_text(text)


print('Logged: {}'.format(text))

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
topic_path = subscriber.topic_path(project, topic_name)

for subscription in subscriber.list_subscriptions(topic_path):
    print(subscription.name)


def receive_messages(project, subscription_name):
    """Receives messages from a pull subscription."""
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        message.ack()

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

    # The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from
    # exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.
    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        print('while loop: ', str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        time.sleep(60)



receive_messages(project, 'test')
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are running on GCE?

Comment: @David I added the GCE code, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS Login is a beta feature, that I couldn't find much about. There is some information at [1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/os-login/), [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/rest/) and [3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google_compute_engine_oslogin/README.md). It seems to be an optional advanced user management system.

The message you are seeing is generated by the the account management daemon that runs you your GCE instance. The message does not indicate a problem as it is just printing current status, in fact it was [recently removed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/commit/ab8ef9ab31e994d9e1a76f29c4e5176da1f5405f) and will stop appearing in future images.

Nothing in your script depends on OS Login or the account management daemon, so it is unlikely that message is related to the issue you are seeing.